# ¿Cómo volver al primer fragment al pulsar back?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Este es mi código para el BottomNavigationView, quisiera saber como hacer para al presionar back regrese al primer fragment y no se cierre la aplicación.

```
  public class Mapa extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapa);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment()).commit();

     BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx = (BottomNavigationViewEx) findViewById(R.id.bottomViewBar);
    bottomNavigationViewEx.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationViewEx);

}

private BottomNavigationViewEx.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {



        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();


            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.mapa:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment()).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.taxi:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new TaxiFragment()).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.help:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new HelpFragment()).commit();
                    return true;

                case R.id.go:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new GoFragment()).commit();
                    return true;

            }


            return false;
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existen varias formas, una es llamando `FragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)` 
 por ejemplo:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(android.R.id.content, new myFragment());
transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
transaction.commit()
```

y para regresar, simplemente remueves el fragmento actual:

```
FragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

---

Si usas las support library debes usar

`getSupportFragmentManager()` en lugar de `getFragmentManager()`.

---

De acuerdo a tu código sería:

```
switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.mapa:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new MapFragment());
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null); 
                    transaction.commit()
                    return true;
                 ...
                 ...
```

y cuando desees regresar

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me sirvió mucho, el detalle es que si apreto 100 veces los botones se regresa 100 veces en la misma secuencia, quiero que al primer back regrese directo a mapa, tal vez lo estoy aplicando mal, incluso al apretar mapa me regresa a mapa y quisiera solo que saliera.

Answer (score 0):

Buscando entre tantos lugares, tenia el mismo problema (*que por cierto no encontré nada realmente útil*), quería regresar al primer fragment y lo que finalmente hice fue hacer prueba y error y llegué a esto:
*Nota: está en kotlin por si queda duda pero es fácil entenderlo y traducirlo

Al momento de establecer el primer fragment en el **onCreate()**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client)

if (savedInstanceState == null)
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, HomeFragment.newInstance())
            .commit()
    ...
}
```

*No añado `.addToBackStack()` porque si lo hago, me regresará al cuando el **FragmentLayout** estaba vacío*

Al momento de añadir un nuevo fragment a **FragmentLayout**

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

Y finalmente para regresar al primer fragment

```
override fun onBackPressed()
{
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1)
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(0,0)
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Por lo que encontré en una discusión (del cual ya no tengo la referencia de donde lo encontré) vi que mencionaba en que mencionaban que `onBackPressed()` se lanza cuando una persona está en un fragment y presiona el botón de retroceso. Si únicamente ejecuto `supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(0,0)` por una extraña razón me lleva al primer fragment que estaba en el "Stack", es decir al segundo  fragment que se puso.